# Gremlin-Javascript: Support for SubgraphStrategy and subgraph step

Tags: javascript, gremlin

I am running through the following tutorial using the Gremlin client for Javascript. Does anyone know if there is support for such strategy? I attempted to use the **subgraph** step but I cant seem to get that working as well.

Tutorial: https://www.datastax.com/blog/2016/09/gremlins-time-machine
Client: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gremlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use `SubgraphStrategy` in javascript at this time - at least not until [TINKERPOP-2054](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2054). `subgraph()` step is not supported in Gremlin Language Variants that are not running on the JVM - at least not until [TINKERPOP-2063](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2063). There are some alternatives to using `subgraph()` step discussed in this [blog post](http://stephen.genoprime.com/snippet/2020/08/01/snippet-12.html), the gist of which is to replace it with `store()` and then develop your own means to handle the graph data on your client side. For some use cases that might be sufficient to solve the limitations of missing that step.

Comment: Thanks for the info Stephen! Good to know these tickets! :)